# Cartesian Product Single Table

Tags: mysql, sql, cartesian-product

I have a very simple MySQL table with three attributs, let's call it word_tbl

id | word | count

I want to combine each row with all rows in the table and sum the value in count. 
The results should be saved in a new table, called cartesian_tbl.
In my opinion, the cartesian_tbl should look like this:

id | word1_id | word2_id | count

My Problem of understanding are the two word_ids which are both a Foreign Key of word_id.id.

Is my schema correct or is there a simpler solution to reach my target?
Thank you for your help!

---

New:

These 2 tables are only an example...

Here a little example how the combination should work
If "Hello" with id 2 has count 4 and "Example" with id 32 has count 5. The new Datarow should look like this
1, 2,32,9

@Francois T
count is only a number

What additional informations do you need?

Comment: Show what you've tried. How else can we tell if you're doing it correctly?

Comment: I tried nothing. I just wanna know if this schema, to handle this kind of data, is correct. Do I have to set 2 Foreign Key to 1 Primary key? Is this allowed?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many foreign keys as you need.

Comment: Try it, and see if it lets you do it. If you get an error, come back here and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO cartesian_tbl (word1_id, word2_id, count)
SELECT w1.id, w2.id, w1.count+w2.count
FROM word_tbl w1
JOIN word_tbl w2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with id auto_increment

And something like that :

but what do you want into count ?

insert into cartesian_tbl (world1_id,world2_id,count)
select word1.id, word2.id, count??? from word_tbl word1 , word_tbl word